# How to prevent XAML grid column from stretching to height of unformatted image?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML written up as part of a Xamarin.Forms project, which has an image in the left column of the grid and some text in the right column of the grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SwinApp.Components.UI.CardExternalLink">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
    <Image x:Name="menuIcon" Aspect="AspectFit" ></Image>
  </StackLayout>


  <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Font="Bold"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I want the image to sit within the left column and not stretch to its full size, which it is indeed doing, however it has a large amount of whitespace above and below it within the column, as though it is still treating it as the full sized image despite displaying it smaller. (Ignore the fact that I have no source set there for the image, I'm setting it through the .cs file as it's supposedly much easier to do that way when using Xamarin.Forms).

Is there some property I am able to place on the left column, the stackpanel or perhaps even the image that would get rid of this excess whitespace?

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you want me to add the .cs file here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the `StackPanel` and set the `Image`'s `HorizontalOptions` and the `VerticalOptions` to `Start`.

Hope it helps!